# Add two instances of a model in same page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add two instances of my model at the same time, that is the user will enter fill the same form in same page and he will send at the same time the two completed references to the database. 
Do you have some idea how can I achieve this ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using jquery ajax. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do (and I'm hoping I'm interpreting your question properly) is have a model set up as such:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your view you would take in a model of Bar (which has contained within it two Foo objects)

Hopefully this helps, could potentially expand on this if specifics are added to your question.

Comment: ok thanks! And then in Create view(form view) there will be the properties of Foo to be filled twice ?

Comment: You can definitely do it by hand, though you might need some specific logic (which would really depend on your specific scenario) to get them written to DB.  I'm not really sure what scaffolding the view based on the Bar model would look like but you can always give it a shot.  I've done what you're talking about before but unfortunately I don't have the code handy.

Comment: I want to have this structure to be fill:                           1st instance of Model                                                                  2nd instance of Model

Comment: I am trying, I will tell you after if I have a problem

Answer (score 1):

Use View model with two properies of your model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public Model ModelA { get; set; }
     public Model ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok but then could I fill all properties twice in one page ? and then add it to the database one reference of Model and another of Model ?

Comment: Yes you can:)You just create two instance of Model and one instance assin to ModelA and Second to ModelB ex. `var veiwModel - new MyViewModel{ModelA = new Model(), ModelB = new Model()};` and return viewModel `return View(viewModel);`